# Building Vue app and use Bootstrap without including in the build

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm learning how to building Vue app now and I'm running into some issue with Bootstrap and Jquery

The website where the app will be deployed to will already have Bootstrap and Jquery loaded as part of the site and I'm only going to add this new Vue application to a section of the site.

I did some looking about this but most of the suggestion is to include Bootstrap-Vue in my Vue build.  I don't want to do this if I don't have to since then I'll be including Bootstrap again on the site.

Is there a way to build my Vue app and compile and have it not throw error when compiling it?

Right now, I can just include the bootstrap css, js and jquery file on the index.html, but as soon as I use Jquery it won't build because I didn't include it in the project, for example :

```
$(".modal").modal("show")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way I think.

In vue.config.js (create if there's none) file add the following

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    configureWebpack: {
            externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
        }
    }
  };
```

And in the component that is using Jquery, add and import

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

In your public/index.html file add the script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    
    <div id="app"></div>
      
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
  </body>
</html>
```